# JMS without any Third Party Messaging

Tags: jms, mq

I have few basic douts.

I have developed a JMS application for P-P and the messages are geeting stored in Jboss 7.1 JMS engine. My questions are below.

1.For any JMS application do we need to have any messaging engine like IBM MQ,HornetQ,Active MQ etc

2. If Yes then we need to configure the MQ to atlk to Appserver Messaging engine.

3.If No, Then we need to have to create a message consumer

Answer (score 2):

JMS is a specification of a messaging interface - and a state model for how messages are handled in transactions.

jms.jar contains pretty much all interfaces - no implementations. Therefore whilst you can write an application against jms.jar you can't actually run it.

You'll need to pick some type of messaging provider. That's appropriate to your requirements.
That's not a discussion for here however keep in mind that they each have possible extensions and functional behavior outside of the specification so if you want to be portable between providers pay close attention to only use specification defined functionality.

Within a JavaEE Application Server there will be a JMS implementation that provides messaging features. Therefore an app here in JBOSS will be a MOM (messaging oridentated middleware) application. If you want the message to be accessed by an application not running in a JavaEE server then that is possible with some providers. There's often a JavaEE client container. Or the messaging engine will have a JavaSE based client that can be used. (WAS thin client client for example).

Remember that with JavaEE servers you are not restricted to a the choice of messaging provider - you can use the JCA interface to directly plug in a external messagin implementation. This might present an easier route if a lot of messaging will be outside the JavaEE server.

EDIT - added JavaEE notes

Comment: Thanks Calanai. Does this means that withouts any third party Messaging technology(IBM MQ,HornetQ,Active MQ etc)our application can not said to be MOM application and Message will remain in APPserver messaging engine.

Comment: When an application is running in a JavaEE app server, it will be using the JMS provider implemented via that app server. [aside using the JCA interface and Resource Adapters you do have a choice]. The messaging engine used is a full JMS implementation so therefore it can be said to be a MOM application. Depending on the exact implementation will determine how easy or hard it is to get the message out to an application not running a JavaEE app server. 

You might be able to write a JavaSE app externally or have to use a app as a bridge between providers. It depends!